# How to change the ImageSource value of the ImageBrush in the DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

Am requesting for help on how i can dynamically change the value of the ImageSource for the ImageBrush contained in the DataTemplate.

Below is my XAML Code :

```
                            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind first_name}" 
                                     Name="TxtFirstName"
                                    Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                    FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic"/>

                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind last_name}"
                                   Name="TxtLastName"
                                    Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                    FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,40,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                                <Ellipse Width="200" Height="200" Name="ProfilePicEllipse">
                                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                                        <ImageBrush x:Name="ProfilePic" 

                                    ImageSource="{x:Bind image_url}" />
                                </Ellipse.Fill>
                                </Ellipse>
                            <Image x:Name="ResultImage" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>


                        </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,40,0,0">

                                <TextBlock Text= "{x:Bind profile}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Margin="10,0,0,0"
                                    FontSize="18" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are already binding the ImageSource to a property, so changing the value of that property ( image_url ) should do the trick! But don't forget to add Mode=OneWay to enable change tracking

Comment: @Depechie Why not write that as an answer?

Comment: @Clemens to be honest because I'm not sure what the actual problem is he's facing :) But could be it's just the Mode... I'll add the answer.

Comment: the issue is with the value returned by the image_url , it returns the value micheal.png and yet the imagesource property expects "http://localhost:8081/bmirs_2015/php_scripts/get_staff_member_photo.php?my_imageurl=micheal.png" . I would like to append ""http://localhost:8081/bmirs_2015/php_scripts/get_staff_member_photo.php?my_imageurl=" to the value "micheal.png" it returns inorder to form a valid ImageSource url value

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the actual problem is.
But seeing you are already binding the source to a property, you can always change the value of that in your code.

Do note that nothing will change on screen if you don't put `Mode=OneWay` to it. Because `x:Bind` default setting is `Mode:OneTime`

So instead of `ImageSource="{x:Bind image_url}"` put `ImageSource="{x:Bind image_url, Mode=OneWay}"`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My problem is the value passed to the image_url is not a valid image path. It returns forexample :micheal.png and the Imagesource requires a full vaild url. I would like to manipulate the value in the image_ur to a full valid imagesource url forexample to : "http://localhost:8081/bmirs_2015/php_scripts/get_staff_member_photo.php?my_imageurl=micheal.png"

Comment: A few possible ways to do that... add an extra property to bind to that does return a valid one. Or use a converter ( but that could be a performance hit )

Comment: Could you please give me a code snippet  example of adding an extra property or how i could use a converter as suggested